# как поймать изменение input[nama=number]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, input

День добрый! Не могу понять, как отловить изменения в input[type=number], когда нажимаются стандартные стрелочки (google chrome).
Изменения при вводе вручную норм, стрелочки на клавиатуре отлично, а вот если тыкать на кнопки по умолчанию у данного input, не срабатывает.
особенно умиляет, что работает один раз, а при втором нажатии и далее, визуально значение меняется, но в js этого не происходит 
https://jsfiddle.net/77354Lb8/

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown change blur', 'input', function() {
  $('#test').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min=0 max=10>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить `mouseup`.

```js
$(document).on('keyup mouseup keydown change blur', 'input', function() {
  $('#test').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min=0 max=10>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ничего лишнего, все просто до ужаса)))

```js
$(document).on('input', 'input', function() {
  $('#test').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min=0 max=10>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Действительно, ваш ответ мне кажется лучше!

Comment: вообще JQ не использую, люблю чисты js, но тут у меня сработала логика

Answer (score 1):

вот вам на **vanilla.js** *чистый javascript*

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]');
const output = document.getElementById('test');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  output.innerText = event.target.value;
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="number" min=0 max=10>
<div id="test"></div>
```